how to fix "Could not create LIST session " error on checkout page
Ii have an e-commerce website. I am using the Woocommerce, and then on checkout page, after fulfilling information correctly and choosing bank transfer payment method  once we click on the button place order, this error appearing ” Could not create LIST session ”
How to solve this error? and why am i facing this error?
below is the website address facing the issue.
https://www.cadrix3d.com
I tried to clear out woocommerce cache and browser cache but no results.
